# Ionic/Cordova - Is there a media/mediaPlayer plugin with working track bar functionality?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, cordova, ionic-framework

Apologies for the open ended question - currently having issues implementing a media player with a track bar that shows the current position and the track's duration. I've tried both the [cordovaNativeAudio](http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/nativeAudio/) and [cordovaMedia](http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/media/) plugins; the native audio plugin is not designed for interactive playback and has no methods allowing retrieval of the duration or current position.

The media plugin, on the other hand, is designed with this in mind - however, on Ionic, as can be seen in the ngCordova docs, the getCurrentPosition() and getDuration() methods are "not working yet".

Is there an alternative? Or has anyone managed to get it to work?

Related to this (possibly) I have just now found a [bug report](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-10723), not sure if it is the same issue as play/pause/stop all work fine on ios and android for me - the roadblocks in my case are currentPosition and duration.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the [JW Player](https://www.jwplayer.com/) which is having very good API for media tracking. It has good support for android, ios and web application.
I tried it for web and ios application and it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

By using below code i got total duration and current position of audio file. Go through the code:

```
    var my_media = new Media(audioFile);
    my_media.play();
    var counter = 0;
    var timerDur = setInterval(function() {
        counter = counter + 100;
        if (counter > 2000) {
          clearInterval(timerDur);
        }
        var duration = my_media.getDuration();
        console.log(duration);
        if (duration > 0) {
            clearInterval(timerDur);
            // duration is the total duration of audio file
            console.log(duration);          
        }           
    }, 100);

    setInterval(function(){
      my_media.getCurrentPosition(function(position){
        if(position > -1){
          // position is current position of audio which is playing
          console.log(position);
        }
      }, function(error){
        console.log(error);
      })
    }, 1000)
```

Note: for every second(1000ms) i am getting the current position